# Probabilities of choosing specific members for a committee

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Problem: From a 10-person group, a 3-member committee is to be formed. Let *A* and *B* denote two different people in the group. Find the probability that: 
 
(a) *A* is chosen 
(b) *A* and *B* are both chosen 
 
(c) *A* or *B* is chosen

Here was my approach to part (a): 
The probability that A is chosen breaks down to the probability of being chosen first, second, or third. Since choosing a person takes them out of the remaining candidates, we have: 
P(A) = 1/10 + 1/9 + 1/8 = 121/360.

I'm not sure how I can approach (b) or (c), however. I would appreciate confirmation/correction of my method for part (a) and hints on how to approach (b) and (c).

Comment: Your answer for part A is not right!

Comment: Evan has provided you with a correct solution.  In your attempt, you also have to pick two more people from among the other nine.  $$P(A) = \frac{1}{10} \cdot \frac{9}{9} \cdot \frac{8}{8} + \frac{9}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{9} \cdot \frac{8}{8} + \frac{9}{10} \cdot \frac{8}{9} \cdot \frac{1}{8} = 3 \cdot \frac{1 \cdot 9 \cdot 8}{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8} = \frac{3}{10}$$ which agrees with the result Evan got using combinations.

Answer (score 2):

a. 9C2/10C3 because you only need to choose two more from the remaining 9 people. And the total possibilities are 10C3

b. 8C1/10C3 because you only need to choose one more from the remaining 8 people.

c.$P(A\cup B)$ = P(A) + P(B) - $P(A \cap B)$  = (9C2/10C3)* 2 - 8C1/10C3

Answer (score 0):

*Another way*

$a. \dfrac3{10}$

$b. \dfrac3{10}\cdot\dfrac29 =\dfrac 1{15}$

$c. \dfrac3{10} + \dfrac3{10} - \dfrac 1{15}$